# Where is Ubercart USPS Shipping module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, ubercart, usps

I can't seem to find the Ubercart 2.x version of USPS Shipping module!

This is the closest I could come, but I feel like I shouldn't be constructing the module from a source view.
http://api.ubercart.org/api/file/ubercart/shipping/uc_usps/uc_usps.module/2/source

There was a zip available here of a spin-off module...
http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/6869/usps_shipping_dimensional_weight_shipping_osc_vs_uber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean U.S. Postal Service?
it is in the Ubercart - fulfillment group.
i guess it came with the ubercart module itself.